# How to make and push object into array inn react Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx

I have one object and I want to push it into an  state array.

`const [values, setValues] = useState([]);`

I am getting the array like that:

`['abc']`

I want to make `abc` as:

`[{Books: 'abc'}, {Books: 'bcd'}]`

How can I be able to do this in react? I am getting an error again and again that map is not a function.

Comment: Show the Code where you use the map() function so we can help you out.

Comment: where are you getting `['abc']` from? Please give us more information

Comment: Its from the library @NullPointerException. I'm using this library https://seawind543.github.io/react-token-input/

Comment: I'm not using map function. The error is coming from the library @yeslamFaded.

Comment: Do you have any code to take a look?. Maybe you are not passing the right data to the library funciton

Comment: Yes sure @kiranvj

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```js
const arr=['abc','bcd'];

setValues(o=>[...o,...arr.map(i=>({Books:i}))])
```

Comment: can you use this library https://seawind543.github.io/react-token-input/.. ?? 

I'm getting error and I want that same array of object you made in this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example you can update your state with _result variable, it works!

```js
const arr = ['abc', 'def'];
const _result = arr.map(item => {
  return{ Books: item }
});
console.log(_result);
```

Comment: can you use this library https://seawind543.github.io/react-token-input/ ?? I'm getting error and I want that same array of object you made in this.

Comment: Please provide your full code.